# jQuery: how do I sort a list where each item is from a different section?

Tags: jquery

Ideally, this would be draggable, and you'd be able to drag stuff from one section into the other.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery UI Sortable plugin has this capability:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists